# cannot get video posts of linkedin company page through api

Tags: linkedin-api

Linkedin api does not include shares with video while fetching all posts of a company page. It wasn't working in both v1 and v2 apis. 
Consider this post with video and it's missing while fetching through api.

> curl "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/12345/updates?format=json&count=20&oauth2_access_token=XXX"

[image]

In v2:

> curl
>   "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:12345&count=25&oauth2_access_token=XXX"
>
> { "elements":[...], "paging":{ "total":24, "count":25, "start":0,
>   "links":[ ] } }

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No. Linkedin also not responding to queries.

Comment: Same here. Youtube includes work fine. Only posts containing a Linkedin video don't get through.

Comment: We're experiencing the same issue. Any update here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the v2/ugcPosts endpoint - see 
 https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/ugc-post-api#get

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the Linkedin API except the video can be found under Linkedin Shares API. 
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/share-api

Videos in Linkedin are simply technically termed as UGCPost-User Generated Content Post
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/ugc-post-api